# How to Select Maximum Value in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, max

I am working on a report with several columns and one of its columns is a Cheque Number. I need to capture the highest check number and display it on the report footer.

Here is some sample data:

```
Cheque Number
100
200
300
400
500
1000
```

I created a formula field called `MaxCheque` and put a formula `maximum({Dtran.ChequeNo})`. I dragged the formula field (`MaxCheque`) in the report footer but instead of displaying 1000 it displays 500.

I tried to research but I was not able to find an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of that column is probably string instead of a number.
Create a formula to convert to a number and do the MAX on that.